# How to resolve C language issues in Objective c file

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode6

Below is a piece of code in my project. Here the error is "cannot initialise a variable of type "uint8_t*" aka (unsigned char*) with rvalue of type void".
When i typecast that method, it will effect to another methods. How can i resolve this issue?

```
uint8_t purchase_info_bytes = base64_decode([purchase_info_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],&purchase_info_length); 
uint8_t *signature_bytes = base64_decode([signature_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], &signature_length); require(purchase_info_bytes && signature_bytes, outLabel); 

void * base64_decode(const char s, size_t * data_len) 
{ 
return NewBase64Decode(s, strlen(s), data_len); 
} 
void *NewBase64Decode( const char *inputBuffer, size_t length, size_t *outputLength); 

You can go through the following URL for screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFHHp.png
```

Comment: Where is `base64_decode` from? What is the declaration of that function?

Comment: Hard to guess, but maybe you're compiling as C++ (which doesn't allow that conversion) rather than C (which does)?

Comment: maybe you are missing the function prototype and a default one is used...

Comment: void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{
    return NewBase64Decode(s, strlen(s), data_len);
}

Comment: void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{
    return NewBase64Decode(s, strlen(s), data_len);
}

Comment: void *NewBase64Decode(
 const char *inputBuffer,
 size_t length,
 size_t *outputLength);

Comment: uint8_t *purchase_info_bytes = base64_decode([purchase_info_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],&purchase_info_length);
uint8_t *signature_bytes = base64_decode([signature_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                                             &signature_length);
require(purchase_info_bytes && signature_bytes, outLabel);

void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{
    return NewBase64Decode(s, strlen(s), data_len);
}
void *NewBase64Decode(
 const char *inputBuffer,
 size_t length,
 size_t *outputLength);

Comment: Put that stuff into the question, formatted, so it can be read.

Comment: "When i typecast that method, it will effect to another methods." How? You will get the error if you compile as Objective-C++, but casting should be fine.

Comment: @UdaykumarGoli How about casting? `uint8_t *signature_bytes = (uint8_t *)base64_decode(...);`, although I would say that `baset64_decode()` is mis-defined to return `void *`.

Comment: Yes it is mis-defined. I have used the third party code. it is working in older versions of Xcode But not in newer versions.